# TypeScript: Type of function with automatic return type by extends generic

Tags: typescript

I try to make typed function whitch returns child type over parent;
We have...

```ts
class X { }

class A extends X {
  hi() { ... }
}

class B extends X {
  hello() { ... }
}

type Foo<T extends X = X> = () => T;
```

Then, i write various functions

```ts
const fa: Foo = () => {
  return new A();
}

const fb: Foo = () => {
  return new B();
}
```

Then, I store result in variables

```ts
const a = fa();
const b = fb();
```

But, if I try to call owned methods of classes A and B, i won`t. Because all types are X

```ts
a.hi() // error
b.hello() // error
```

How correct this mistake if you can not set generic manually, like `a = fa<A>()` ?

Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to specific the return type for `fa` and `fb`.

Comment: Shouldn't your `Foo` be `type Foo<T extends X = X> = () => T` or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I have made mistake =) thanks!

Comment: Sysix, type of function need for arguments typing, like `type Moo<T extends X> = (arg: Foo<T>) => T` and etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start from `class X`. This class does not have any methods.

You expect `Foo` to accept one generic parameter with default value `X`.

Since you have defined `fa` and `fb` functions with type `Foo` without explicit generic parameter, default value has been applied.

In fact, each function has type of `Foo<X>`. Since `X` does not have any methods, you are not allowed to call them.

If you want to make a function which returns any class inherited from `X`,
consider this example:

```js
class X {
    tag: 'X' = 'X'
}

class A extends X {
    hi() { }
}

class B extends X {
    hello() { }
}

class C {}

const fa = () => {
    return new A();
}

const fb = () => {
    return new B();
}

const x = <T extends typeof X>(arg: T) => new arg();

const a = x(A) // ok
const b = x(B) // ok;
const c = x(C) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1XQC5gOYC5oHJZ9oBeAopAXySVEhgEFoBTAD3WYDsATGeZNNAAWASwAUASkTRq1WuCjQAQi3ZdecRCjRDmIEAHtJ02TTqKAwojnADnCOmgAzMKWjGSAPi2CATs3QAV19OaE5mAHdoBkkAbiozOwdnACM3D28BNH8gkLDI5TiE2iTHVjcAHgAVVQ4eGHQATwAHZgMnOE8xMF9caCqpL3yonqwikvtHVzJWMQYpAHoF6AMAawnktJmxJUXltfjbSehgN1mLPZZfXwNfIA)

Please keep in mind, that TS has structural type system, this means that `class X{}` and `class C{}` are equal from type point of view. To make sure TS is able to distinguish them you need to add some property to `X`. I added `tag`